# Finding All Neighbors in N-Dimension Array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I find all the neighbors of an element in N-Dimension Array in MatLab?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the coordinates, just go 1 forward and 1 back (if possible) in all directions. If you want diagonal neighbors as well you also have to try all the combinations of going 1 forward, 1 back, or 0 forward (except 0 in all directions of course).

Comment: @user1924748 - If you find Dennis's answer useful and correct, the polite thing to do is to accept it. Just click the checkmark to the left of the answer; Dennis will get reputation points and you'll probably even get a badge for accepting your first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code [for computing adjacency matrix](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html#adjacency).
It computes neighbors for all entries in arbitrary dimensions.

**EDIT:**

You may want to explore Matlab's [`conndef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/conndef.html) as well.